# Unable to compile the class for JSP

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, rhel

We are facing the below exception when I click on View button to see the user details :

```
2017-06-30 19:23:52,831 ERROR [com.myapp.jsp] - <Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 53 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/jsps/ViewUserDetails.jsp
apache cannot be resolved or is not a field
50:                     </myapphtml:myappRow>
51:                                         
52:                     <myapphtml:myappRow align="left" label="userdetails.field.label.orgs">
53:                         <logic:iterate name="userDetails" property="Orgs" id="org">         
54:                             &nbsp;<bean:write name="org" property="name" /><br>
55:                         </logic:iterate>
56:                     </myapphtml:myappRow>


Stacktrace:>
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 53 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/jsps/ViewUserDetails.jsp
apache cannot be resolved or is not a field
50:                     </myapphtml:myappRow>
51:                                         
52:                     <myapphtml:myappRow align="left" label="userdetails.field.label.orgs">
53:                         <logic:iterate name="userDetails" property="mappedOrgs" id="org">           
54:                             &nbsp;<bean:write name="org" property="name" /><br>
55:                         </logic:iterate>
56:                     </myapphtml:myappRow>


Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:490)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:379)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:662)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:364)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:410)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1063)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:263)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:386)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:318)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:229)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at at com.myapp.tools.auth.client.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:512)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at com.myapp.tools.auth.client.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This happens only in the combination of RHEL 7.x and Tomcat combination.
I am not able to reproduce this issue in combination other then this.

Attaching the **ViewUserDetails.jsp**

```
<%@ page import="org.apache.struts.Globals" %>
<%@ page import="com.myapp.tools.api.impl.User" %>

<%@ include file="include/commonDef.jspf" %>

<tiles:insert definition="myapp.csd.office.layout.default">

    <tiles:put name="header" type="String">
        <myapphtml:myappPageHeaderTab headerImage="images/default/icn_user.gif" headerText="form.page.title.user_details"/>
    </tiles:put>

    <tiles:put name="content" type="String">
        <myapphtml:myappBlock>
            <myapphtml:myappMessage
                    genErrorKey="<%= myappGlobals.GENERAL_ERROR %>"
                    valErrorKey="<%= Globals.ERROR_KEY %>"
                    genErrorHeading="MC.General.genError"
                    valErrorHeading="MC.General.genError"
                    headingBundle="myappBASETAG"/>
        </myapphtml:myappBlock>

        <strutshtml:form action="/processUserList.do" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="" />



                    <myapphtml:myappRow align="left" label="userdetails.field.label.orgs">
                        <logic:iterate name="userDetails" property="Orgs" id="org">         
                            &nbsp;<bean:write name="org" property="name" /><br>
                        </logic:iterate>
                    </myapphtml:myappRow>



            <myapphtml:myappButtonRow formname="UserDetailsForm">
                <myapphtml:myappButton action="cancel" name="form.button.label.cancel" buttonStyle="button_gt" />           
            </myapphtml:myappButtonRow>         
        </strutshtml:form>

    </tiles:put>

</tiles:insert>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to see if you have a String called `org` change it to other name as `org1`.

See [answer](http://techierg.blogspot.co.il/2011/07/jsp-compilation-error-apache-cannot-be.html).

> String org = ""; something like this in jsp somewhere on the top of
> that package statement. Change that variable name to org1 or some
> other meaningful one and your problem will be solved.

There's a [known issue](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42475) in Tomcat which its Compiler is interpreting this as a reference to the field apache of object org

> The code works in TC4 because the generated code is much simpler - it
> ignores a number of possible error conditions. The fix for these
> issues in TC5 and TC6 includes a fully qualified reference to
> org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.URLEncode()
>
> The complier is interpreting this as a reference to the field apache
> of object org.
>
> When you have generated code, there is always going to be the
> possibility of a naming clash. I can't see an easy way around this.
>
> I am going to mark this as WONTFIX. More generally, avoiding the use
> of widely used package prefixes (org, com, etc) as variable names will
> reduce your risk of hitting this issue.
>
> As an aside, a quick Google suggests you might also want to avoid 2
> letter variable names that clash with top level domains.

Notice that [RHEL](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/77133) uses a specific tomcat version which not as community version.

> Any community releases of Tomcat are not supported
>
> The supported releases of Tomcat are included in our products:
>
> Tomcat rpm package included in RHEL 7.1, which is based on Tomcat
> 7.0.54.
>
> Please note that we backport critical bug and security fixes on the
> above versions when issues are raised or CVEs are reported. Therefore,
> the versions we provide are not exactly the same as community versions
> of Tomcat.

Comment: Am i supposed to change the value in the jsp or the java code in backend?
if in jsp, I tried that and didn't work. It gave me the same exception with org1.

Comment: It resolved the issue but  can you tell me why this worked? is the "org" keyword is reserved in the rhel or java or anywhere?

Comment: add details of a known issue

Comment: @ user7294900 This issue doesn't occur in the platforms other then RHEL+tomcat. So is this specific to this platform or this is specific to tomcat?

Comment: @ user7294900 is this the java which comes specific for RHEL env, causing the issue with the tomcat?

Comment: what are the other combinations you tried ? can you specify?

Comment: I added more info about RHEL and tomcat version

Comment: I tried RHEL+weblogic, RHEL+Websphere, Windows+weblogic, Windows+Websphere, Windows+Tomcat. But only combination which I saw error is in RHEL+Tomcat.

Comment: Yes because there's a problem with some versions of tomcat, and RHEL use specific version of tomcat which isn't community version.

Comment: yes I used tomcat 8.0.43 which is not a community version but I think in tomcat 7 and 8 any version would be having the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149087/discussion-between-deepak-jain-and-user7294900).